# How do i include only one CSS file in the html head when I import multiple .scss files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, gatsby, head

My websites have a structure that looks kind of like

```
src/
    components/
        Footer/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
        Header/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
        Navbar/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
...
```

In each of my `index.jsx` files, I have `import './style.scss'` in it.

In a [Gatsby website](http://suddenlysask.com) I developed recently, I can only see one style tag in the head, even though I probably have a couple dozen components containing `import ./style.scss`.

[image]

I am now developing a non-Gatsby, React & Webpack website, using the same method when my components contain `import ./style.scss` a lot of the time, but it looks like there is a style tag for every imported style file.

[image]

I'm wondering what Gatsby does, and how I can include the same sort of functionality in my non-Gatsby website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work is done by [webpack](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/webpack/), not by Gatsby. Of course, Gatsby extends from a custom implementation but you can import the same behavior into another project by adding a custom webpack configuration ([as you can do in Gatsby as well](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/)).

webpack bundles all JavaScript, JSON, and CSS (by default does not support SCSS, it should be achieved by adding a custom webpack's configuration or via plugins) file using a [code-splitting technique](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/). This allows you to divide your code across a few bundles that are loaded as needed or as requested.

In addition, one thing that may work for you, is to use major files to collect some imports. Given:

```
src/
    components/
        Footer/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
        Header/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
        Navbar/
            index.jsx
            style.scss
```

You can create under `/src/styles` a file called `styles.scss` and:

```
@import 'components/Footer/style';
@import 'components/Header/style';
@import 'components/Navbar/style';
```

Then import the file in the top-level component that contains the other ones.

---

Update:

The warnings that you are talking about are due to a wrong importation [order in styles](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#ignoreorder). There are not important since webpack chunks all those styles but they create a warning. There a property called `ignoreOrder` (set by default as `false`). You can fix it by:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      ignoreOrder: true, // here
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm hoping to not have to import them all into one css file

Comment: Of course not, but it helps to sort the global styles and avoid repetitions, it's off the question. Your issue must be handled through webpack splitting.

Comment: Didn't notice that you've updated your question with some trials. @Sam I've updated the answer with the solution to avoid the `ignoreOrder` issue.