# Gatsby CSS loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I have a little trouble understanding how CSS is loading with Gatsby framework. From what I read, all CSS is being processed by webpack and put in the head tag, meaning all styles for all pages will be included right after the page is loaded for the first time. Is there any way I can load CSS only for pages and components the user wants to see?

Comment: [Might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009664/6331353)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i include only one CSS file in the html head when I import multiple .scss files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008164/how-do-i-include-only-one-css-file-in-the-html-head-when-i-import-multiple-scss)

Comment: yep, thank you guys, everything you sent helped a lot